# Cancel out horizontal Parallax movement

Tags: parallax

I implemented a parallax in my code but the buttons move horizontally as well as vertically. Is there any way I can cancel the horizontal movement out without losing my vertical movement? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I believe you are translating on both axis, simply translate only along one axis. If possible, share your code:D